# "Suggest" Usage

Tags: grammar, verbs

I had a Grammar homework and I was asked to fill in the gap of the following sentence :

***My father ... subscribe to the Newsweek.***

I had been given four options and only one of them fits in with the sentence, they are as follows :

A- *Said to me*

B- *Suggested that I*

C- *Suggests me to*

D- *Encouraged me*

I had chosen the answer "C" but I discovered later that the teacher considered it as incorrect, and that "B" is the appropriate answer, which made me so confused. Could you please explain to me why ?

Comment: “suggests me to” is never correct.

Answer (score 3):

This has a simple answer: of those four answers only *suggested that I* fits the blank. None of the other answers has a form which the verb *suggest* 'licenses'—permits.

But there are two questions hiding behind the one you ask, which will in the long run be more important to you as a student of English.

1. *Why did you make this mistake? What made you think that* "My father suggests me to subscribe ..." *is a better answer?*

Of course we can't read your mind, and we have no idea what exactly you have learned in your studies. But it's a pretty safe bet that you were reasoning by analogy to more familiar constructions—perhaps one or more of these:

> My father tells me to do such-and-such ...
> My father asks me to do such-and-such ...
> My father orders me to do such-and-such ...
> My father urges me to do such-and-such ...
> My father encourages me to do such-and-such ...

The problem with this sort of reasoning is that it won't work, or if it *does* work, it's pure coincidence. Every verb has its own pattern of 'complementation'—the sorts of phrases and clauses which it licenses to complete its thought. For instance, *suggest* licenses these sorts of complement:

- noun phrases — *My father suggested a subscription to* Newsweek. *In this case it's an* object rather than a complement.
- gerund clauses — *My father suggested subscribing to* Newsweek.
- mandative finite clauses — *My father suggested (that) I/we/he subscribe to* Newsweek.

  Some "authorities" say that the mandative one, with 'subscribe', is a use of the subjunctive, others that it's a use of the infinitive. I'm usually convinced by whichever I read last; but it doesn't really matter what you call it as long you are aware that *suggest* does **not** license infinitival clauses in which the infinitive is marked with *to*.

The important thing is that you can't reason from another verb's complementation pattern, even if the other verb means exactly the same thing. So the second question is

2. *How do you avoid this kind of mistake?*

Unfortunately, there's no easy answer. Each verb's complementation pattern has to be learned individually.

But it's not that hard to find out what sorts of complement a verb licenses. Whenever you learn a new verb (or are unsure about an old one), start by looking it up in a good dictionary, one that gives you example sentences; that will give you at least one acceptable complement. For more examples look in a corpus such as Google Books, or a more carefully curated formal corpus like those at [*BYU*](https://www.english-corpora.org/), and search on "he *VERB*ed"—that will give you a full range of acceptable complements, and will usually provide you many more clues to acceptable uses.

Answer (score 1):

Subordination in English is one of the more complex areas of the grammar, and I didn't study this until my honours year. That anyone ever gets is is amazing.

*Suggest* (this particular version anyway) takes a full S (sentence) as a complement, subordinated by an optional *that*. So in effect, when you see a sentence with *suggest* in it, you should be able to remove everything up to *suggest(s) (that)*, and the result should be complete, and grammatical.

> My father suggested that I subscribe to Newsweek.

In the above, *I subscribe to Newsweek* is a fully complete, grammatical  sentence.

*Encourage* works differently. It does not take a complete S as its complement; it takes what Lexical-Functional Grammar calls an XCOMP, which is essentially a non-finite verb phrase. As it's a verb phrase, it lacks an agent (ordinarily mapped to subject), which it must absorb from the matrix clause, and it lacks tense inflection, which it inherits from the matrix clause.

Consider the following:

> I subscribe to Newsweek.

*I* is the agent, and *Newsweek* is the, well, patient (not exactly, but it'll do). Agent maps to subject, patient maps to object. Easy.

> He encouraged [ me to subscribe to Newsweek ]

Here, *me* is the agent of *subscribe*, but it comes out as *me* rather than *I*, the accusative form. What's happening here is that the matrix clause *he encouraged me* supplies its object, *me*, to the subordinated clause to act as the agent of the verb *subscribe*.

To make matters worse, there are intransitive verbs that take an XCOMP as well, but in those scenarios, there's no object of the matrix clause to act as the agent of the subordinate clause, so instead it uses the subject of the matrix clause:

> I promise to do the dishes.

It is *I* that does the dishes, which that clause gets from the matrix clause.

So to sum, B is correct. D would have been correct if it had been *encouraged me to*.

Which verbs work like *suggest* and which like *encourage* is just something that you have to learn; there's no pattern to it, it's simply arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

(C) is wrong because "suggest", just like other verbs of Latin origin (*describe, explain, propose, indicate, announce, communicate, confess, dictate, prove, reveal, transmit*), always takes the indirect object ("me", in this case) with the preposition "to", whether the indirect object is placed before or after the direct object. (C) is also wrong because it never takes "to"-infinitival but gerundial complements.

You could say -- but it would be unnecessarily redundant because of the coexistence of "me" and "I" -- the following:

- My father suggests **to me** that I (should) subscribe to the Newsweek. (The use of "should subscribe" is typically BrE, while the use of the subjunctive "subscribe" is more usual in AmE.)

Of the four options provided, only (B) is grammatical. Additionally, you could say:

E- My father suggests **my subscribing** to the Newsweek.

Answer (score 0):

Option A would work if *subscribe to the Newsweek* were put into direct speech - but not in indirect speech.

Option B is correct: My father suggested (what?) - that I subscribe to the Newsweek.

Option C is wrong because (as Jim remarks) you can't *suggest me to*.
You can:

> Suggest (that) I/we/he/she/they close the door

but not *me* and not *to close the door*.

Option C would work with a different verb than *suggest*:

> My father advised/counselled/encouraged me to subscribe to the Newsweek.

Option D would have been correct if it had read: *encouraged me to* subscribe to the Newsweek. *To* was missing.

Comment: And then there's this to explain: "How did you get nominated for the job?  My father suggested me."

Comment: @Xanne You can suggest (put forward) anybody, including *me* as a candidate for a job vacancy. But you can't say that he *suggested me to* - unless it's *suggested me too*.

Comment: "Suggest", then, can take a direct object--"My father suggested a diet of white rice."  But, I can say "My father suggested me to the committee," because here "to" is a preposition, not part of an infinitive.  And I can say "If my father _suggests me to_ the committee, I will not serve."

Comment: @Xanne An excellent point, well made!